# MySQL: Get N records for each group with sum()

Tags: mysql

I have the following table containing items from different groups:

```
Item   GroupName   Price
  A          G1       10
  B          G1       3
  C          G1       8
  D          G2       6
  E          G2       12
  F          G2        8
  G          G3       3
  H          G3       8
  H          G3       5
```

I want to select one item (any) from each group, where total sum is less than X and return N possible combination. 
E.g.
sum(item G1, item G2, item G3) <=21 ;2 items (N) from each group and the output can be:

```
Items       Sum
A, D, J        21
C, F, G        19
```

I found a solution to select N records from each group:

> SELECT Item, Price FROM ( SELECT Item, Price, @rank := IF(@prev_group = GroupName, @rank + 1, 1) AS rank, @prev_group := GroupName FROM TABLE_NAME JOIN (SELECT @prev_group := NULL, @rank := 0) AS tv ORDER BY GroupName, Price DESC) as T2 WHERE rank <= 2

but have to idea how to add

> where SUM(Price)<=21

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This isn’t really what SQL is good for.

Comment: You should not do it with mysql. All you have to do is to get DISTINCT groupNames and find the possible combinations programmatically.